# Python 3.6 - pickle

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import pickle

randomlist = []
value = input("Add: ")
randomlist.append(value)
print(randomlist)

with open("randomlist_presistence.pkl", "wb") as pickle_out:
    pickle.dump(randomlist, pickle_out)
```

It creates a file called: "randomlost_presistence.pkl" and it has some symbols. But afterwards I don't know what should I do to unpickle the data. I don't know where to write this:

```
with open("randomlist_presistence.pkl", "rb") as pickle_in:
   randomlist = pickle.load(pickle_in)
```

My goal is to write something into the list and save it. Python 3.x. Thank you.

Comment: "I don't know where to write this". Wherever you intend to open the file and use the pickled object??

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense now! But my goal is to write something into the list and save it with pickle. So then I could write more and more into the list and get it saved. But that's not what is happening.

Comment: Just load the pickled list, append to it, and dump it back into a pickle object. By creating a pickle, you're not makiung some object that is somehow automatically sync'd with the object. It's a serialized object so that you can load it somewhere else or at another time. If you need to modify it, load it back in, change it, then write it back out.

Comment: I have a feeling you're trying to get around a different issue, possibly a scope issue where you can't access a list in another functiuon. Is this the case? I/O (reading and writing from/to disk) is slow, I'm just curious if you're trying to share an object that way.

Comment: No, I'm just trying to make simple list, where I can put random numbers and it would be saved by pickle, so I could close it safely and whenever I want to add numbers, I just simply add them to existing list that was created/saved before. I thought of a simple project, but it's going slowly due to this. Thank you

Comment: Thank you sir! Everything is working! Appreciate it!! @roganjosh

Answer (score 1):

You can tests if the file exists then load it before you add extra elements. You can initialize the list as you did if the file does not exist.

```
import pickle
import os  # need os.path.isfile

if os.path.isfile("randomlist_presistence.pkl"):  # check if the file exists
    with open("randomlist_presistence.pkl", "rb") as pickle_in:  # here
        randomlist = pickle.load(pickle_in)

else:
    randomlist = []

value = input("Add: ")
randomlist.append(value)
print(randomlist)

with open("randomlist_presistence.pkl", "wb") as pickle_out:
    pickle.dump(randomlist, pickle_out)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read your pickle file in using the open function. In the example below x now contains your list read in from the pickle file.

```
with open('randomlist_presistence.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    x = pickle.load(f)

print(x)
['testing']
```

Comment: You mean, by using exactly the same approach that they already have in their question?

Answer (score 0):

Pickle is a protocol to serialize data, that is to convert data to string. You can use this format to save python objects efficiently or to do some nice things like sending objects to different processes in RAM or to other nodes of a network. There is no a precise place in which you must load the file. Simply load it whenever you need (maybe in another program?)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `open` from within `pickle.load` / `pickle.dump`. Here is an example:

```
import pickle

lst = [0, 1, 2, 3]

# save pickle file
pickle.dump(lst, open('file.pkl', 'wb'))

# load pickle file
x = pickle.load(open('file.pkl', 'rb'))  #  [0, 1, 2, 3]

# append item and save
x.append(4)
pickle.dump(x, open('file.pkl', 'wb'))

# reload pickle file
x = pickle.load(open('file.pkl', 'rb'))  #  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```